# Barcode scanning issue in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, barcode-scanner

We are facing an issue with the IE version 8 related to the barcode scanner.
The issue is, in the first scan of barcode in IE8, the scanner doesn’t return the CR suffix. We need to hit enter button manually and then when we scan the same barcode again and it is working fine. We are facing this issue only on the first scan in IE 8. In all other browser, the scanner is working fine.
We have written the code in .Net MVC framework to read the barcode scanner values.

Here is the code:

-------------------Knockout code----------------------------

```
self.PackageValidator = function (data, event) {

    $("#success").hide();
    $("#error").hide();
```

}

-------------------------HTML Code-----------------------

input id="packageIdentifier" data-bind="value: TransferClass.ProductIdentifier, event: { change: PackageValidator }" type="text"

---

Please let us know if anyone has any solution for this issue.

Regards,
Vipin Singhal

Comment: The below function is automatically called after scanning the barcode. But, in IE8, in first scan, this function is not called,we need to press Enter button to call this function:

-HTML Code-
<label>@Resources.Resources.lblPackageId</label>
 <div class="inputDiv">
   input id="packageIdentifier" data-bind="value: ReceiveClass.PackageIdentifier, event: { change: PackageValidator }" type="text">
 </div>


-Package Validator Knockout Code-

    self.PackageValidator = function (data, event) {

        $("#success").hide();
        $("#error").hide();
}

Comment: user, please add the code to your post by clicking edit instead of as a comment to the post.  Thanks.